# Prove that a finitely generated free abelian group has a finite basis.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G = \langle g_1,g_2,...g_r\rangle$ is a free abelian group. Let $H\subset G$ be a basis of $G$. Then $|H|$ is finite.

Here is a proof given in class which I don't understand:

Let $(h_i)_{i \in I}$ be any basis of $G$. Show that $|I|$ is finite.
Each $g_i$ is a linear combination of finitely many $h_i$. Hence there are $i_1,..,i_n \in I$ such that $G=\langle h_{i1},...,h_{in}\rangle$.
If there were $h_j$ such that $j \notin \{i_1,...,i_n\}$, then $h_j = m_{1}h_{i1}+...+m_{n}h_{in}$ for $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, not all of which are 0, contradicting the linear independence of the basis $(h_i)_{i \in I}$....

What I don't understand is why each $g_i$ is a linear combination of finitely many $h_i$?

Comment: What did you try, specifically,? and where, specifically, did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm guessing by $|H|$ you mean the rank of $H$ ?

Comment: Sid You really need to address those questions I asked  in your post.  If you ignore me, and simply hope for an answer, anyway, all we can do is assume you've thrown us a homework problem and expecting us to do it for you.

Comment: Well I have the proof given in class, but I don't quite understand it. The proof goes something like this: Let $(h_i)_{i\in I}$ be any basis of $G$, show that $|I|$ is finite. Each $g_i$ is a integer linear combination of finitely many $h_i$, ... What I don't understand the justification of "each $g_i$ is a integer linear combination of finitely many $h_i$"

Comment: it is just the definition of basis

Comment: but why finitely many?

Comment: A linear combination is defined only for finitely many members (without introducing any further notions such as limit or something..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(h_i)_i$ is a *basis* of $G$, by definition, each element of $G$ - in particular, each $b_j$ - can be uniquely written as a $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of $h_i$'s. 
By the definition of ($\Bbb Z$-)linear combination, only finitely many $h_i$'s can be used in that. 
All in all, for writing all $b_j$'s, only finitely many $h_i$'s are used.